# HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.LinkageError - Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, maven, servlets, web.xml

I'm trying to configure a simple page with JSP and getting an error.

My web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>ERPWep-calendar</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>calendar</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>CalendarConnector</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>calendar</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/events.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>calendar.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

CalendarConnector is working perfectly. But the JSP's in the `WebContent` is not being readed. It show me the following error:

```
Jun 12, 2015 3:19:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/ERPWeb-calendar] threw exception [java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/calendar_jsp, and the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class objects for the type he.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager; used in the signature] with root cause
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/calendar_jsp, and the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class objects for the type he.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager; used in the signature
    at org.apache.jsp.calendar_jsp._jspInit(calendar_jsp.java:53)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:179)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My calendar.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello world!
    </body>
</html>
```

My pom.xml, I think is everything correct here:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ERPWeb-calendar</groupId>
  <artifactId>ERPWeb-calendar</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1-b03</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1-b03</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <parent>
    <groupId>ERPWeb</groupId>
    <artifactId>ERPWeb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need `<scope>provided</scope>` on `org.apache.tomcat` in your `pom.xml`